# Accepting return type void from a method?

Tags: java, methods, types, parameters, void

i am developing a testing class, which allows users to put in arbitrary method calls. Then my class will trigger them.

```
static class UserClass {
    static String method_01() { return ""; }
    static void   method_02() {}
}
class MyTestUtil {
    void test() {
        // HowTo:
        // performTest( <Please put your method calls here> );
        performTest( UserClass.method_01() );       // OK
        performTest( UserClass.method_02() );       // compile error
    }
    void performTest(Object o) {}
    // This is only a simplified version of the thing.
    // It is okay that the UserClass.method_calls() happens at the parameter.
    // This captures only the return value (if any).
}
```

The second `performTest()` is having the following compile error.

> The method performTest(Object) in the type Main.MyTestUtil is not applicable for the arguments (void)

### In short, i am finding a way to accept the *thing* that is returned from a `void function()`, into a method parameter.

*(or into a variable - not much different)*

```
static void function() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    this_function_accepts ( function() );   
    // The method this_function_accepts(Void) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (void)

    Void this_var_accepts = function();
    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Void
}
```

i have done a bit researches. And i realised the class `java.lang.Void`. But it only accepts `null` or the type `Void`(with big V), which is not `void`(small v), and not normal to users' methods.

```
// adding these overloading methods doesn't help
void this_function_accepts() {}
void this_function_accepts(Void v) {}
void this_function_accepts(Void... v) {}
void this_function_accepts(Object v) {}
void this_function_accepts(Object... v) {}
```

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect this to work at all.  `void` methods don't return anything.  Why would you want to do this?  What would `performTest` _do_ with no result?

Comment: Your solution is not going to work even for non-void methods. The problem with your approach is that the call of the method that you are supposed to test is going to happen before the call of the `performTest` method. Essentially, your `performTest` is going to get the return value of the method being tested - it wouldn't be able to invoke the method or feed it any parameters.

Comment: In your example, performTest() is not being passed a method that it can run after setup and teardown -- it's being called *after* the method has already run, with the *result* of the method call.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for your comment. Yes i know it. It is ok to invoke it at the parameter and `performTest()` just capture the return value (if any).

Comment: Then why have a `performTest` method at all?  What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.  If you just want to invoke a method, then just invoke that method.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman @ dasblinkenlight @ Andy for the comments and spotting that issue. Let me explain. In fact `test()` will `return performTest(!isInvoke() ? "UserClass.method_call()" : UserClass.method_call());`. When `isInvoke()` returns false, `test()` will return the String and get it printed somewhere else. When `isInvoke()` returns true, the method is really invoked. Why i have to wrap this in `performTest()` because it does some further checkings. i may have to redesign the thing. But is there a way to accept/determine `void`?

Comment: Actual arguments to methods are values. The void keyword indicates that a method has no return value. You can't pass as a value the return value of a void method, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I have finally redesigned the class, so no methods need to take `void` parameters. :) If it is a must, i think Reflection would be a nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to solve this problem would be to have the `void` methods return [`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) instead, which you've already called out. The `void` type will never be accepted as a value type in Java, so the style you're using won't work for `void`.

Another approach would be to allow users to provide a `Runnable`, which is then run on their behalf, and then have them call the `void` method in the `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may have to look into `Runnable` and it may solve my problem.